# Implementing "title formatting" in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a "title formatting" parser in Python, a la foobar2000 and Winamp. It basically works like this:

```
"%artist% - %title%" -> "The Beatles - Yellow Submarine"
"%title% by $upper(%artist%)" -> "Yellow Submarine by THE BEATLES"
```

That's a simple example; look [here](http://media.winamp.com/main/help/50/atf/atf.htm) or [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000%3aTitle_Formatting_Reference) for reference.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried -- and failed -- with regex and lex/yacc.

> **EDIT**: Along with `%variables%` and `$functions()`, I also have to implement single quotation marks (which surround raw text) and square parentheses (see the references!).

Answer (score 1):

Does it *have* to be in that exact format? Python's own string formatting is nice:

```
>>> tags = {'title': 'Yellow Submarine', 'artist': 'The Beatles'}
>>> tags['upperartist'] = tags['artist'].upper()
>>> '{title} by {upperartist}'.format(**tags)
'Yellow Submarine by THE BEATLES'
```

For anything much more complicated, I'd pick one of the many [Python templating engines](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating). Templates are fun to write - that's why there are so darn many of them! - but I bet one of them would already do just when you want.

Comment: Well, it has to be able to call functions, at least.

Comment: I added a link to a bunch of template engines you might want to check out. The web guys have this stuff down.

Answer (score 0):

Well multiple regex calls are an option.

To recognize a variable you should use `%\w*%` and to recognize a function call `\$\w*\(\w*\)`

You then incrementally search for variables and substitute them for their value and for function calls and substitute them by passing the data inside the parethesis to an actual function and pasting the result. Is that what you tried?

Comment: Yes, but I came to a stumbling block with implementing quotation marks. Quotation marks surround raw text, effectively escaping metacharacters like `%` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample I wrote that might help. You will need to expand `subs`, `functions` and `apply_func` as per your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
# Variables to be substituted
subs = ["title", "artist"]

# Functions to be applied
functions = ["upper", "lower"]

# How to apply a function to the argument
def apply_func(f, arg):
    if f == "upper":
        return arg.upper()
    if f == "lower":
        return arg.lower()

def get_title(title, values):
    # Substitute the variables first
    for s in subs:
        title = title.replace("%"+s+"%", values[s])

    # Apply the functions
    for f in functions:
        fre = re.compile("\$("+f+")\((.*)\)")
        result = fre.search(title)
        if result:
            arg = result.group(2)
            title = title.replace("$"+f+"("+arg+")", apply_func(f, arg))

    return title

def main():
    #title = "%title% by $upper(%artist%)"
    title = "$lower(%artist%) -> $upper(%title%)"
    values = {'title' : "Yellow Submarine", 'artist' : "The Beatles"}
    print get_title(title, values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not really helpful for solving stuff past the simple examples I gave (see the references I posted, if you're interested), but thanks for the effort!

Comment: @mbradley This is a sample. You can expand this to solve your problem. Should be easy from here.